# Send webcam output over Internet

Tags: networking, video, webcam

So I will not be home for a few days and would like to see what's happening at my front door.
I have a laptop with the latest xubuntu on it and with a decent quality webcam wich is what i would use to record.

The laptop isn't very powerful therefore I want something very lightweight to prevent the fans from spinning.

Now the question is: is there a way to share this video output over the internet so I can view it from my phone? I know skype/discord can do this but they require my phone to be in a call and that would drain the battery drammatically.
Something like 1 or 2 fps or even less is fine but I'd prefer a non-compressed image.

Is this accomplishable in some way? Preferably I'd also want the video recorded if it detects movement.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: What about access this home computer when you are away? That is what I do and I think it might be simpler overall.

Comment: How could I do that?

Comment: I am away currently and access my home machine via VPN.